# Manipular borda de 1 pixel para evitar dupla borda (1+1 pixeis) com elementos lado a lado

Tags: css, css3, css-border

Tenho uma grelha criada com uma lista `ul` cujos elementos internos às `li` contém uma borda.
A ideia é que quando os elementos estão lado a lado as bordas sejam manipuladas para que fique apenas um único traço com 1 pixel ao invés do que acontece:

[**Exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/e73EU/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Problema

Como a lista deve ficar com uma largura de 100% da área onde se encontra inserida e os respectivos elementos `li` devem ficar com 25% da largura da lista, a borda cinza está aplicada no link `a` dentro de cada `li` de forma a evitar que os 25% de largura mais os 2 pixeis que a borda (1px borda direita + 1px borda esquerda) ocupa quebrem o layout:

**HTML**

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="">1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="">2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="">3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="">4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="">5</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="">6</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="">7</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="">8</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
ul, li, a{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul{
    width:100%;
}
li{
    float:left;
    width:25%;
}
a{
    border:1px solid #c9c7c7;
    text-align:center;
    height:200px;
}
```

## Pergunta

Como fazer para que o resultado final das bordas cinzentas fique com o aspecto em baixo apresentado ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A quantidade de quadrados é fixa ou dinâmica?

Comment: @KennyRafael A grelha é como apresentada, mas no futuro podem ser necessárias mais linhas! As colunas serão sempre quatro.

Comment: E esse conteúdo é gerado com PHP?

Comment: Qual é o conteúdo disso? Usar uma tabela com `border-collapse` estaria fora de questão por motivos semânticos?

Comment: @bfavaretto Fora de questão por causa das animações via jQuery que vão ser aplicadas, caso contrário já lá estava uma tabela :)

Comment: @Zuul, este conteúdo é gerado manualmente ou via PHP ou outra linguagem?

Comment: @KennyRafael PHP, mas se possível prefiro fugir de uma solução que fique dependente do "gerador" da lista.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Com certas regras de CSS3 é possível afetar apenas algumas das bordas para atingir o resultado desejado:

```css
/* apaga todas as bordas direitas e inferiores */
li a { 
    border-right-color: transparent; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
/* mostra borda direita a cada 4 itens */
li:nth-child(4n) a { border-right-color: #c9c7c7; }
}
/* mostra borda inferior nos últimos 4 itens */
li:nth-last-child(-n+4) a { border-bottom-color: #c9c7c7; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e73EU/1/

**Solução alternativa para resolver a lacuna de 1px**

```css
li a { 
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-width: 0;
}
li:nth-child(4n) a { border-right-color: #c9c7c7; }
li:nth-last-child(-n+4) a { border-bottom-width: 1px; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e73EU/4/

#### Suporte

- **Pseudo-classe `nth-child`**: [IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child)
- **Pseudo-classe `nth-last-child`**: [IE9+](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child)

Comment: Só lembrando que caso esteja trabalhando com navegadores incluindo o IE8, seletores como nth-child não funcionam...

Comment: Incluí agora links com detalhes sobre suporte.

Comment: Uma opção é utilizar estes seletores com o Jquery, assim funcionará em qualquer navegador!

Comment: Quase lá, mas fica um quadradinho da cor do fundo (branco), devido à ausência de cor na borda.

Comment: @Zuul Complicou. Adicionei uma segunda opção que resolve isso, mas você precisa conhecer o número de linhas da grelha (ou escrever CSS para linhas extras), e o conteúdo fica um pouco deslocado para cima.

Comment: @Zuul Substituí minha segunda solução por uma melhor, mais genérica.

Answer (score 1):

O jeito mais simples de se fazer isso, é utilizando box-sizing e bordas concentradas tanto na UL, quanto nas LIs. Veja:

```
ul, li { 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  border-left: 1px solid #999;
  border-top: 1px solid #999;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li {
  border-right: 1px solid #999;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```